# The problem associated with filters in wordpress/woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a website for sales on wordpress and recently I noticed a bug, it means that when I filter products by brand, price, etc.,and after that I go to the page of any product and then when I click the back arrow in the browser, the site breaks.
When not a single filter is applied to products, then everything is fine.

Please tell me what could be the problem?

Here is a screenshot of the problem:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEw15.png)

Comment: Is this site currently online? If so, please provide the URL. It looks like the functions file or template  is not loading the CSS and header files correctly

Comment: Yes, he is online. Here is the [link](https://electromotor.md/categorie-produs/iluminare/), put any filter, after that go to any product and back

Comment: I just got a "Resource Limit Reached" message. This is looking more like a server issue than a wordpress/programming issue

Comment: [This](https://fliktraxcdn.s3.amazonaws.com/resource_limit.png) is what I was receiving more than a few times

Comment: This is bad, try going to the main page of the [site](https://electromotor.md/).
Does the problem remain?

Comment: There is helpful info for WordPress for this error code [here](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9366/2194/errors-500-502-504-and-508-reasons-and-ways-of-fixing#508)

Comment: It seems to be intermittent, but the problem seems to be a matter of upgrading to a higher capacity server environment. If that's not possible, than I suggest some caching implementation.

Comment: I can’t upgrade to a higher capacity server environment, but the problem remains. Or caching implementation not a solution to the problem or am I doing something wrong :(